# Simpledateformate timezone not converting

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

In java simpledateformat i am not able to convert to the timezone for  IST. The input I am giving is in UTC but I want to convert to IST.

```
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = format1.parse("20-01-2019 13:24:56");
        TimeZone istTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
        format2.setTimeZone(istTimeZone);
        String destDate = format2.format(date);
        System.out.println(destDate); //2019-01-20 13:24:56
```

But it has to add +5:30 to make it IST.

Comment: You haven't set the time zone in `format1`, so it's using your local time zone by default. Set the time zone of `format1` to UTC if that's what you intend it to be.

Comment: Use `java.time` classes, as ZonedDateTime, DateTImeFormatter, easier to use

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter` and `ZoneId`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Tip: To maximize compatibility, get in the habit al always including the padding zero and the colon in an offset-from-UTC. So `+05:30`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added timezone output and explicit UTC timezone assignment to format1 to your code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(format1.getTimeZone());
    TimeZone utcTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    format1.setTimeZone(utcTimeZone);
    Date date = format1.parse("20-01-2019 13:24:56");
    TimeZone istTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
    format2.setTimeZone(istTimeZone);
    String destDate = format2.format(date);
    System.out.println(destDate); // 2019-01-20 13:24:56
```

You should see that SimpleDateFormat defaults to your local timezone. Setting UTC explicitly should work.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

As said in another answer, you did not set time zone for `format1`. You can also use `java.time` package to solve this problem since java8.

Since `20-01-2019 13:24:56` does not contains time zone information, you can:

1. parse it as `LocalDateTime`.
2. convert the `LocalDateTime` to `ZonedDateTime` in UTC.
3. get the same instant in time zone IST.

Example:

```
DateTimeFormatter format1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTimeFormatter format2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = LocalDateTime
        .parse("20-01-2019 13:24:56", format1) // parse it without time zone
        .atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")) // set time zone to UTC
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")); // convert UTC time to IST time

System.out.println(format2.format(zonedDateTime)); //2019-01-20 18:54:56
```